# Изменить прозрачность только фона

Tags: html, css

Есть код

```css
.block-theree {
  background-image: url('../image/3.png');
}
```

```html
<div class="row block-theree">
  <div class="large-12 columns text-center">
    <h3 class="white font-opensans bold">TRAIN RIDES</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Могу ли я как нибудь изменить прозрачность фона при этом не менять прозрачность текста?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например с псевдоэлементом и абсолютами:

```css
.block-theree{
  position: relative; 
}

.block-theree:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image:url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bf/Blue_Tiger_Im_IMG_9450.jpg);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  
   opacity: .5;
}

.block-theree div {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;  
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row block-theree">
  <div class="large-12 columns text-center"><h3 class="white font-opensans bold">TRAIN RIDES</h3></div>
</div>
```

Или с градиентом:

```css
.block-theree{
  position: relative; 
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.5),rgba(255,255,255,0.5)), url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bf/Blue_Tiger_Im_IMG_9450.jpg);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.block-theree div {  
  /*height: 200px;  высота только для наглядности */
}
```

```html
<div class="row block-theree">
  <div class="large-12 columns text-center"><h3 class="white font-opensans bold">TRAIN RIDES</h3></div>
</div>
```

Comment: а если высота блока меняется, то как сделать?

Comment: уберите `.block-theree div {  
  height: 200px; /* высота только для наглядности */
}`

Comment: ну тогда ничего не будет, там же content:''

Comment: Чего не будет? Сейчас исправила, все есть. Если будет контент, то будет и фон тянуться.